# RenderComponentField function in dream weaver template is not working in Web 8.5

Tags: 2011, experience-manager, web8.5

As I have migrated the CM database from 2011 to Web 8.5 , there are some dwt TBB which contains `RenderComponentField()` function . At the time of preview the function is throwing error.

But when I tried to render the field by using the `@@field_name@@` it is working fine.
Is there any way to make the `RenderComponentField()` function to work in Web 8.5 as I can see this function is obsolete in web 8.5. 
Or if replace this function with `@@field_name@@` will the ExperienceManager tags will work properly?

Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in the TOM.NET Programmers Reference Guide the function `Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Expression.BuiltInFunctions.RenderComponentField` is marked as obsolete.

They suggest to use `FieldStartMarker(String)` and `FieldValueStartMarker()` instead. If you want this fields to be editable from XPM this is the way. You can check the examples [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-73AAE413-324C-45F4-88B8-E71A3DF176BD&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-73AAE413-324C-45F4-88B8-E71A3DF176BD.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-73AAE413-324C-45F4-88B8-E71A3DF176BD).

If you just want to display the field value you can go ahead with `@@foo@@` or `${foo}` expressions, or with `GetFieldValue` function.

I recommend you to check this article in the SDL Documentation that describes how to upgrade your deprecated functionality: [Replacing `RenderComponentField()` calls in your templates](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-5FA45B5C-7F8C-4772-928D-B69BA9BEF6E4&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-5FA45B5C-7F8C-4772-928D-B69BA9BEF6E4.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-5FA45B5C-7F8C-4772-928D-B69BA9BEF6E4).

*edit: updated links for Web 8.5.*

Comment: Yes this one is working. I need to replace the function with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

It`s working fine for me. please try dwt as below code:

```
@@RenderComponentField("title",0)
```